# Animation nodes bake material attribute output

Tags: animation, node-editor, baking

I have a simple scene with a cube going upwards. The cube has emission material that changes colour (blinks) based on the cube's z-location (this is done through animation nodes).
I would like to bake the blinking effect into the material, but I was unable to figure it out so far. I'm using the "Set Keyframes" nodes with custom property set to emission color data path but I get "Could not set keyframe" error in the Set keyframes node.
Is it possible to bake such animation with AN?
[image]

Comment: Does it have to be animation nodes to animate the shader or could it be also an animated shader?

Comment: @Chris it has to be done through animation nodes as this is just an example of a more complicated effect.

Comment: @Gorgious thanks for the suggestion, but the value you proposed also leads to the "could not set keyframe" error

Comment: and an animated color in AN won't help? Can you tell us why do you need this baked to keyframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

ok, i tried and i think i have a solution for you.

The node setup is this:

[image]

Of course you have to update this to "your" material in the expression nodes, but then it works. I deleted the animation nodes tree and the baked animation changes z-Position and changes the material.

result baking:

[image]

result after baking with deleted AN-tree:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! Your solution works!

Comment: You are welcome!